# Trying to parse json code from console in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel

I have 4 addresses fetched from DB and I used geocode API and itarate it into json.

```
@foreach($estates as $est)

    var result = $.ajax({
            url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={{$est->address}}&key={{env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API')}}'
        })

    result.done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);

    });

@endforeach
```

But now how can I parse just lat/lng from console?

Comment: Why are you passing the script in a foreach loop?

Comment: because datas are coming from controller, so i pass it right away to get geocodes @AmmarHussain any other option?

Comment: Why are you consuming an api in a script tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ajax get instead of a `<script>` tag like this:

```
@foreach($estates as $est)

    var result = $.ajax({
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={{$est->address}}&key={{env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API')}}'
    })

    result.done(function(data) {

        {{ get required data and save to somewhere }}

    });

@endforeach
```

You can get more info here about how to do this:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: thank you for answer mate. but with this I fetching nothin in the console.

Comment: change this line `{{ get required data and save to somewhere }}` to `console.log(data);`

Comment: okay thank you :) but I have two problem I only getting first one and If use foreach then I get nothing. the second problem is lat and long is inside these how can I get those? https://imgur.com/a/jzcGpBU if you help me the solve this problem really appreciate it!

Comment: I added already but it says "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

Comment: thank you! it solved the first problem! How to go in results.geometry.location and get lat/long?

Comment: I solved the last question. Thank you mate gave me really big help about code!

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the api. One way is to use get_file_contents. Here is an example code.

```
@foreach($estates as $est)  

    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={{$est->address}}&key={{env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API')}}";

    $resp_json = file_get_contents($url);

    $resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);

    if($resp['status']=='OK'){
        // Get Latitude and Longitude from resp variable
    }

@endforeach
```

**EDIT 1**

Get Lat and Lng from JSON Response.

```
if($resp['status']=='OK'){

    $lat = isset($resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']) ? $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] : "";
    $lng = isset($resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']) ? $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'] : "";

}
```

Comment: thanks for this. I updated the question's code. how can I get the location's lat and lng?

Comment: I have updated the code. Please have a look and if it satisfies your need please accept my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I already solved the problem mate but thank you for helping me out I upvoting you.